# EasyMock - mocking abstract methods inherited from an interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm having some difficulty with EasyMock (3.1) class mocking.  This is supposedly suitable to mock partial class implementations, which, I figured, should be ideal to unit test abstract base classes while mocking out the missing method(s).  Here's the pattern - an instantly recognizable classic...

```
public interface Interface {
    public void intfMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractBase implements Interface {
    public void otherMethod() {
        // do some stuff we need to test...
        intfMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the test:

```
public class TestAbstractBase {
    AbstractBase testInstance;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testInstance =
            createMockBuilder(AbstractBase.class).addMockedMethod("intfMethod").createMock();
    }
    @Test
    public void testOtherMethod() {
        testInstance.intfMethod();  // expect this to be invoked on the mock...
        replay(testInstance);
        testInstance.otherMethod();
        verify(testInstance);
    }
}
```

EasyMock doesn't seem to like this.  It throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method not found (or private): intfMethod
    at org.easymock.internal.MockBuilder.addMockedMethod(MockBuilder.java:78)
    at TestAbstractBase.setUp(TestAbstractBase.java:19)
```

Any ideas?  I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412988/how-do-i-mock-a-method-inherited-from-an-abstract-class-with-easymock) but it doesn't really do justice to its title...

Comment: What happens if you just remove the `addMockedMethod` call? The documentation on partial mocking says "abstract methods are conveniently mocked by default".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks to @nhaldimann ; I'd overlooked this [innocuous statement in the doc](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock2_5_2_ClassExtension_Documentation.html#Partial_mocking), namely that "abstract methods are conveniently mocked by default".  So all the above needs is to remove the attempt to explicitly mock the interface method, as in:

```
testInstance = createMockBuilder(AbstractBase.class).createMock();
```

While researching this, I came across two other workarounds - although the above is obviously preferable:

1. Use the stronger `addMockedMethod(Method)` API, as in:

   ```
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       Method m = AbstractBase.class.getMethod("intfMethod");
       testInstance = createMockBuilder(AbstractBase.class).addMockedMethod(m).createMock();
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly expose the `intfMethod` method in `AbstractBase`

These two workarounds suggest that my initial issue is a bit of a bug on the EasyMock side of things.  But since there's no need to mock that method in the first instance, we'll say this is "user (my) error".